# Trim search params prior to search using Find

Tags: excel, vba, find

Is there a way to trim the parameters of a search using `Find` prior to the search?

I have an Excel file that I would like to search through to find a cell with a particular word in it; each cell contains only one word. The `Find` function is case-insensitive and works perfectly for the most part. The only (possible) flaw that I have found is that the cell must contain ONLY the word without leading and trailing spaces.

For example:
If I want to search for the word acoustic using the `Find` function

```
Dim rng as Range
rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K100")
Set foundItem = rng.Find("acoustic")
if not foundItem Is Nothing Then MsgBox foundItem.Address
```

This will find the word in its many variations - "Acoustic", "aCOUstic", "acouSTic", etc. but will NOT find it if it has a leading or trailing space, such as "    acoustic" or "acoustic    ".

So, is there a way to (easily) trim the spaces off the cell prior to performing the search? Or will I have to create a function to go through the range and trim first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trim the range prior to finding:

```
rng.value = Application.Trim(rng.value)
```

Or if the range has formulas and you want to keep them:

```
rng.Formula = Application.Trim(rng.Formula)
```

Comment: Wow.... you are all over this VB stuff. I knew you could trim, but had no idea you could trim an entire range that way. This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Apolymoxic you're welcome. You can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147564/trim-function-remove-spaces-from-cells-using-vba/42148229#42148229) for different methods to trim a range.

Answer (score 1):

just set `LookAt` parameter of `Find()` method to `xlPart`

```
Set foundItem = rng.Find(What:="acoustic", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase=False)
```

you can also make the same search in formulas:

```
Set foundItem = rng.Find(What:="acoustic", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase=False)
```

and be informed that you should always explicitly specifcy `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` parameters, otherwise `Find()` will use their last settings even if from Excel UI!
(I found it sufficient for my purposes to always specify at least `LookIn` and `LookAt` parameters)